# Unique value based on for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a data frame as below:

```
data = {'Name':['Mathew', 'Mathew', 'Mathew', 'Mathew','Mathew','John','John','John'],
        'Age':[12,12, 12,13, 13,12,13,13],
       'Colour':['Yellow','Blue','Yellow','green','blue','pink','black','brown']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I tried a loop as below. I need the unique value in based on the loop. Like, Name is mathew and age is 12, mylist contain the values yellow and blue.

```
for j in set(df.Name):
            for i in set(df.Age):
                #my_list=list of unique colour produced in according to each loop
                    print(i,j)
```

output of above code will be as follows:

```
12 John
13 John
12 Mathew
13 Mathew
```

But what i want as output is,df.Name is mathew and df.age is 12, then mylist will be as follows:
my_list=['yellow','blue']

Comment: Could you show an example output?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. But if it is just to lose duplicates then you could add the line df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)

Comment: I need the unique values of each loop.--->df.Name is mathew and df.age is 12, then mylist will be as follows: my_list=['yellow','blue']

Comment: @user19077881```
12 John,
mylist=[''yellow'',''blue'']
```

Comment: just like that for other values too if 13 John then mylist=['black','brown']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique values within Pandas group of groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880388/unique-values-within-pandas-group-of-groups)

Comment: nope..its not by groupby. I need to findout using for loop..after running those two loops, I need to findout the corresponding unique values of colour

Comment: why no groupby? who you insist on a for loop?

Comment: I need to pass the corresponding list to other operations.

Comment: see my updated answer. Still need your for loop ? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution in a for loop:

```
for name in set(df['Name']):
    for age in set(df['Age']):
        print(name, age)
        my_list = df.loc[(df['Name']==name) & (df['Age']==age),'Colour'].unique().tolist()
        print(my_list,'\n')
```

Output:

```
Mathew 12
['Yellow', 'Blue'] 

Mathew 13
['green', 'blue'] 

John 12
['pink'] 

John 13
['black', 'brown']
```

other approaches:

```py
out = df.groupby(['Name','Age'])['Colour'].unique()
print(out)
```

Output:

```
Name    Age
John    12             [pink]
        13     [black, brown]
Mathew  12     [Yellow, Blue]
        13      [green, blue]
Name: Colour, dtype: object
```

To make it a bit more clear, since you seem to be a bit confused. `out` is a pd.Series where you have for each index (which is a pair of name and age) all unqiue colors as an array.

Since you really want single lists as output, here you go:

```
John12, John13, Mathew12, Mathew13 = df.groupby(['Name','Age'])['Colour'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x)))

print(John12)
print(John13)
print(Mathew12)
print(Mathew13)
```

Now you have 4 single lists for each combination, which you can use anywhere else.

```
['pink']
['black', 'brown']
['Blue', 'Yellow']
['blue', 'green']
```

Comment: for j in set(df.Name):
            for i in set(df.Age):
                out = df.groupby(['Name','Age'])['Colour'].unique().reset_index()
                print(out)
you mean like this?

Comment: no, you don't need the for loop. out is the result which let you know all unique colors for each name/age combination.

Comment: I need to pass the values after this loop. Is it possible to findout using for loop? I need the output inside the for loop

Comment: have a look again. I showed you a way in a for loop.